# Are arrays a const pointer in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers

Is it true that C++ array is a const pointer in C++ ?

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/10/#msg1381

So why is `x` and `&x` the same if they are pointers?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int x[5];
    int *y = new int[5];

    cout << "&x : " << &x << endl;
    cout << "x : " <<  x << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "&y : " << &y << endl;
    cout << "y : " <<  y << endl;
    return 0; 
}
```

Output:

```
&x:  0xbfec4ccc
x :  0xbfec4ccc

&y:  0xbfec4ce0
y :  0x8961008
```

Link to ideone of above code:
http://ideone.com/3JRZd

Comment: You can show the same problem with `sizeof`. `sizeof(x) != sizeof(y)`. (In your ideaone link.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not true that an array is a const pointer in C++. Indeed if one file contains

```
extern int* const a;
```

and the other contains

```
int a[10];
```

in the same scope, combining both files will cause strange errors.

However, arrays *decay* into pointers in most situations. More exactly, if you use an array in an rvalue context, it is implicitly converted into a pointer to its first element. This is what happens to x in the example in the second link: Since the first element of the array of course is at the same address as the array, both `x` and `&x` are printed as the same address. However note that they are *not* the same pointer because they are of different types: `x` in this context decays into `int*`, i.e. pointer to `int`, while `&x` is of type `int(*)[5]`, i.e. pointer to array of 5 `int`s.

Another case where you can see that both are different is a function taking a *reference* to an array, like

```
void f(int (&arr)[5]);
```

You can pass `x` to this function (because it is of type `int[5]`) but neither `&x` nor the pointer `y` you get when writing `int* y = x`;

Comment: It is realy the best answer.
(array is implicitly converted into a pointer)
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

Graham is wrong and doesn't know what he's talking about. Arrays and pointers are two different things.

Comment: I 100% agree with GManNickG. That arrays are "just pointers" is a common C/C++ misunderstanding. They can decay into pointers, but when they don't, they are different. And when they do, they are *still* different because they have to decay.

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
int array[3];
```

is **NOT** the same as

```
int const *array=new int[3];
```

just for simple, but not single reason: you will need to call `delete [] array` in the second case.

Comment: To be fair, it's entirely allowed to implement automatic allocation via dynamic allocation. What's important is that the compiler manages the delete for us.

Answer (score 1):

Silly analogy:

Consider the address *1, Main Street*.
It is not the same thing as the street "Main Street", despite the fact that you can refer to the beginning of Main Street as "1, Main Street". In fact, if you want to meet someone at that end of the street, you can give them a note with the address "1, Main Street" on it as a pointer to where to wait for you, which is much easier than fitting all of Main Street onto a bit of paper (or giving them a map with an "X" on it, if we allow ourselves to introduce an abstraction layer).

*1, Main Street* is of course not only the address of the beginning of Main Street but *also* the address of the first house on Main Street - this is what your printing of `x` shows - but neither a house nor an address *is* a street.

Answer (score -1):

yes they are.

because a pointer is always an address so the &value should be the same for any type of pointer.

also you can do something like this

```
int number[] = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
int *pNumbers = number;
```

[edit] maybe not per the other answers ... but i was always under the impression this was true
[edit] also see http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/ under "pointers and arrays"